# App crashes after launching on OS 3.1

Tags: exception, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-3.1, crash-reports

I need help to understand the crash log i received from the client. The app works fine on my phone but it crashes with him. I have OS 3.0 installed here while my client has upgraded to OS 3.1.

Client reported app crashes usually when he starts the app.

Why I am getting EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)? Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

```
Incident Identifier: AA3A4B6A-BD0D-473F-B1D2-EF9655A0116E
CrashReporter Key:   f3a4736dc8d450a3cb0ecb7367313dbbd816c484
Process:         MyApp [730]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/D0F3BF28-B790-4CE4-8A40-08577C4B34C9/MyApp_36.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2009-10-05 17:10:07.101 -0600
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1 (7C144)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a002 0x31423000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
4   GraphicsServices                0x325323a0 0x3252e000 + 17312
5   UIKit                           0x3314ec28 0x3314b000 + 15400
6   UIKit                           0x3314d228 0x3314b000 + 8744
7   MyApp                           0x00002090 main (main.m:13)
8   MyApp                           0x0000202c start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a002 0x31423000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
4   WebCore                         0x31e196f0 0x31d95000 + 542448
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a002 0x31423000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
4   Foundation                      0x31382998 0x31328000 + 371096
5   Foundation                      0x3137bac6 0x31328000 + 342726
6   Foundation                      0x31329d0e 0x31328000 + 7438
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308312f0 0x3080b000 + 156400
1   CoreFoundation                  0x314437e2 0x31423000 + 133090
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089c720 0x3080b000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083e4d8 0x3080b000 + 210136
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083dc9c 0x3080b000 + 208028
3   PhotoLibrary                    0x32f545b8 0x32f11000 + 275896
4   Foundation                      0x3137bac6 0x31328000 + 342726
5   Foundation                      0x31329d0e 0x31328000 + 7438
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089c720 0x3080b000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083e4d8 0x3080b000 + 210136
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083dc9c 0x3080b000 + 208028
3   CoreMedia                       0x30635660 0x30630000 + 22112
4   CoreMedia                       0x3063553c 0x30630000 + 21820
5   MediaToolbox                    0x30bc0bb4 0x30bbd000 + 15284
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080db48 0x3080b000 + 11080
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080d9b0 0x3080b000 + 10672
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31427bc4 0x31423000 + 19396
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3145f2ee 0x31423000 + 246510
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3145bb90 0x31423000 + 232336
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3145b9c0 0x31423000 + 231872
6   Foundation                      0x3136d29c 0x31328000 + 283292
7   Foundation                      0x3136f990 0x31328000 + 293264
8   Foundation                      0x31345668 0x31328000 + 120424
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3149e8a2 0x31423000 + 506018
10  CoreFoundation                  0x314612f4 0x31423000 + 254708
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3145feca 0x31423000 + 249546
12  CoreFoundation                  0x31496fd6 0x31423000 + 475094
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3144c4e8 0x31423000 + 169192
14  CoreFoundation                  0x314b7de2 0x31423000 + 609762
15  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3431288c 0x3430a000 + 34956
16  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32d51a84 0x32cee000 + 408196
17  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32d51afc 0x32cee000 + 408316
18  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32d51c24 0x32cee000 + 408612
19  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34310e54 0x3430a000 + 28244
20  CoreFoundation                  0x31449b2c 0x31423000 + 158508
21  CoreFoundation                  0x31449acc 0x31423000 + 158412
22  Foundation                      0x3134970a 0x31328000 + 136970
23  Foundation                      0x3136f520 0x31328000 + 292128
24  MyApp                           0x0002c4aa -[BlogViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] (BlogViewController.m:239)
25  UIKit                           0x331eae98 0x3314b000 + 655000
26  UIKit                           0x331ea5a0 0x3314b000 + 652704
27  UIKit                           0x33198428 0x3314b000 + 316456
28  UIKit                           0x33160428 0x3314b000 + 87080
29  UIKit                           0x33197e04 0x3314b000 + 314884
30  UIKit                           0x331977b8 0x3314b000 + 313272
31  MyApp                           0x0002c738 -[BlogViewController loadMessagesThread] (BlogViewController.m:135)
32  Foundation                      0x3137bac6 0x31328000 + 342726
33  Foundation                      0x31329d0e 0x31328000 + 7438
34  libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089bb5c 0x3080b000 + 592732
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089bb4a 0x3080b000 + 592714
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089bb3e 0x3080b000 + 592702
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308b2e64 0x3080b000 + 687716
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32d54390 0x32cee000 + 418704
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34312898 0x3430a000 + 34968
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32d51a84 0x32cee000 + 408196
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32d51afc 0x32cee000 + 408316
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32d51c24 0x32cee000 + 408612
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34310e54 0x3430a000 + 28244
10  CoreFoundation                  0x31449b2c 0x31423000 + 158508
11  CoreFoundation                  0x31449acc 0x31423000 + 158412
12  Foundation                      0x3134970a 0x31328000 + 136970
13  Foundation                      0x3136f520 0x31328000 + 292128
14  MyApp                           0x0002c4aa -[BlogViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] (BlogViewController.m:239)
15  UIKit                           0x331eae98 0x3314b000 + 655000
16  UIKit                           0x331ea5a0 0x3314b000 + 652704
17  UIKit                           0x33198428 0x3314b000 + 316456
18  UIKit                           0x33160428 0x3314b000 + 87080
19  UIKit                           0x33197e04 0x3314b000 + 314884
20  UIKit                           0x331977b8 0x3314b000 + 313272
21  MyApp                           0x0002c738 -[BlogViewController loadMessagesThread] (BlogViewController.m:135)
22  Foundation                      0x3137bac6 0x31328000 + 342726
23  Foundation                      0x31329d0e 0x31328000 + 7438
24  libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x10004005    r1: 0x03000006      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000450
    r4: 0x00001403    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2ffff59c
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x038fc098     r10: 0x03000006     r11: 0x00000450
    ip: 0xffffffe1    sp: 0x2ffff560      lr: 0x3080f09c      pc: 0x3080c4b8
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x3cfff +MyApp armv6  <7bfba5c63a8d3386a2f6773e22bed2e5> /var/mobile/Applications/D0F3BF28-B790-4CE4-8A40-08577C4B34C9/MyApp_36.app/MyApp
   0xeb000 -    0xecfff  dns.so armv6  <957f94410f77a351749ac39d2b4b4abe> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6  <c9ed2fd4b6ad0b603479d414cb382dd5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30005000 - 0x30011fff  CoreVideo armv6  <c31d33c7629e4f7b14a659f06f17674e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30061000 - 0x30078fff  OpenGLES armv6  <c31f4982bc65e67356e9b692f9976b1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30079000 - 0x301cdfff  AudioToolbox armv6  <065ac06f6e9f6bc62555565581a50637> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x30218000 - 0x30223fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <28bbad866f148b0d0adda83a01cec8f8> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3035d000 - 0x3040afff  ImageIO armv6  <8d44717aa7e4314848108d49b42ce576> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3040d000 - 0x30441fff  Security armv6  <36f9d8ca8c4e037e14edd6ae95524b24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3045f000 - 0x30493fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <818346d31133d475739fe3c3b35b5bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30630000 - 0x30677fff  CoreMedia armv6  <07c13fb5ab31a52dfc3a50be02898f1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3067b000 - 0x30687fff  IAP armv6  <3752a21b994225b12069f929bf9b19d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30725000 - 0x3072dfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <6673f222acee5f3a208169712387862a> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x307a9000 - 0x307b7fff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <c4d3d79ffaa7e13f556cd5f9c9fceff2> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x307b8000 - 0x30808fff  Celestial armv6  <6ccb9601cfba52fc5b7740e70fb565b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30809000 - 0x3080afff  CoreSurface armv6  <12f13b59faf0107d8536963b1552c481> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3080b000 - 0x30931fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <7bcb29dde047a859e6f57f2e9e63d38f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30986000 - 0x30988fff  ArtworkCache armv6  <49b8fea9eb3f6e7d2241d94cc241bbd2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x309f6000 - 0x309fbfff  ITSync armv6  <cad602d917d800f848e522d835c3a031> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30b45000 - 0x30b4bfff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <74ead45f4f6840457b982e3a5cc30055> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30b4d000 - 0x30b79fff  CoreLocation armv6  <ac2b8ebbcb03f7a57c61c9a5eaa5b3d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30b7e000 - 0x30bbcfff  VideoToolbox armv6  <15ea0e25a764b445ce59401f09c2787d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30bbd000 - 0x30cd3fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <4930d982e746b906ca6fac74e30d361b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x30eb7000 - 0x30eb9fff  Camera armv6  <83d973c375886b5c4632beae0cea27c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Camera.framework/Camera
0x30ef7000 - 0x30f16fff  Bom armv6  <fcd9e839c0d1a25cbf59a08cc60fea3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30f1a000 - 0x30f1cfff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <db3c3a983db3d53f6199dafb8b472bfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31043000 - 0x3112afff  MusicLibrary armv6  <3deebbf46222551b71d0121b6360308b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x311a4000 - 0x311abfff  MobileMusicPlayer armv6  <5492f53cedd0e55e1fd504a087b65e08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileMusicPlayer.framework/MobileMusicPlayer
0x311ac000 - 0x31221fff  MediaPlayer armv6  <8e2efee9a7b8abcfddec740e95c87ed3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31222000 - 0x31224fff  AppleJPEG armv6  <d28a5dc54781356536addeb4ed7235ab> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x31225000 - 0x31322fff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <303af93622bcb0c4b68ed62b55d124fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31328000 - 0x31420fff  Foundation armv6  <8ddca22a76a5f2bc91f55c87eea8e9a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31423000 - 0x314cffff  CoreFoundation armv6  <a40c65b893c6ca5c0b632d2804ad59d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x314fc000 - 0x31556fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <e346522412f1e957d9cee6511c66bdc9> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31557000 - 0x31557fff  vecLib armv6  <c8a08b45effd5eb35a476a969628e52d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31558000 - 0x3155bfff  MobileInstallation armv6  <e9617b1538fe22f2d6eb91156d130409> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3155c000 - 0x3156efff  TelephonyUI armv6  <cf3ba0b4f4141796c0b7b376b48b4f20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x3158f000 - 0x315fcfff  CFNetwork armv6  <19088cf3f0b4f667b52482ac6ab99690> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31603000 - 0x3160dfff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <8c6d9927c48ad08cfae540d60af17b6a> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x3160e000 - 0x31617fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <a2849d569ba1e7a4083aec5be693f055> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31622000 - 0x3165ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <640dc156b068d347f6c83a27adad6d06> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31660000 - 0x3169efff  CoreText armv6  <c21aa763bf62e82e8a1f062c3e201e84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3169f000 - 0x316abfff  DataAccessExpress armv6  <c16ab7cb09e768e26ea3fa714475b691> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x316ac000 - 0x316bcfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <f1b3998fcf7b60cee74b3e03fc94bf31> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x317c5000 - 0x31872fff  WebKit armv6  <b555f14fc6c288f8725843055d936507> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31d2b000 - 0x31d2bfff  Accelerate armv6  <21e1dc9fad96f0d51afbeb7f7e006aaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31d95000 - 0x324e8fff  WebCore armv6  <28b391254b0edba93084f458e5805787> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x324f7000 - 0x3251efff  AppSupport armv6  <d8d247ecb9f5a3ff92583048a5da264c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3252e000 - 0x32539fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <8629b6affa7c7752ab3c702f1c694325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x325f8000 - 0x326eefff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <893355592f660060653383b29f42d102> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x326ef000 - 0x32729fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <cf9cc6079374718dce29cba9de48b993> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32744000 - 0x3274cfff  AccountSettings armv6  <9d0822c54adc0f81b866543fc34196bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x32848000 - 0x32895fff  IOKit armv6  <035ec9372089422af1ccdb17d72ac091> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x328da000 - 0x328e9fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <6d87ea09ffe173f3d356514e7382bd95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3290a000 - 0x329b4fff  QuartzCore armv6  <cb65d19d96053b411b9a1c68f8f20a33> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x329d6000 - 0x329f4fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <e2f1ba98b2a7b91e91896cea1db932e4> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32a2d000 - 0x32be7fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <58e0bf5baaceb205917d03050a0ac954> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32c71000 - 0x32cedfff  AddressBookUI armv6  <f617c0012f4d5caf1c0cc0fad2fc8c2e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32cee000 - 0x32d58fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <1982380fa8b60e63fd29559efb58d1f0> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32d59000 - 0x32d5afff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <436a03767758117cc9ecec8417f2d185> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32eb0000 - 0x32eb7fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <faaee75832afeaf9d352318edd62970b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x32eb8000 - 0x32ef2fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <56a514c096120e8a1e1bb52b8645699b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32f11000 - 0x32f94fff  PhotoLibrary armv6  <e37c2ebe58a035ef13164d834fa12699> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x330ce000 - 0x330f1fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <5e02a84096d714b4f8a38aa8f4107b85> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33110000 - 0x33148fff  TextInput armv6  <a13cc5ea542bf5d4a66256e1c7ca0cee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3314b000 - 0x33f3cfff  UIKit armv6  <dfcffbbb1e8813d91fe5fd5daf69ed11> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33f74000 - 0x33fd5fff  GMM armv6  <45ce64a42afbb59806bf588439b4bfc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x33fe5000 - 0x34040fff  CoreAudio armv6  <92290f4dba14837427eaa399a55929cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34150000 - 0x34156fff  MBX2D armv6  <0e5d686d0e641a8efc5dc2003c37e2f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x34170000 - 0x3418efff  AddressBook armv6  <d221b21a3d8594abc8ee717ae6f77076> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3419b000 - 0x341a5fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <48254d8d389dc9ecf90688e227ddba1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x341f0000 - 0x341f4fff  IOSurface armv6  <1b951baaae45efbbae825b670612f478> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x341f5000 - 0x342f6fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <aceb70042ae76cfec9838f6771db48d8> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3430a000 - 0x343adfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <c3df9efc40404bc1865caacbf6209a1e> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a crazy thought: install 3.1 on your iPhone so you can test your app and keep your client happy.  Exactly how long would it take you to install 3.1?

Comment: But it is the best way - you have to have the same environment as your client

Answer (score 0):

The first log, there's just not enough info in the stack to say why it crashed.  It seems most likely that some UI element was released somewhere and still being referenced, though that is kind of a wild guess.

The second one though, is telling you that when the user pressed the lock button while in your app, it took too long to return from the method that processed the notification the application was suspending - so it was killed.  You need to check whatever method you have activating on suspend and see what is taking so long to run there.

Comment: On second log: I have not implemented the "applicationWillResignActive" or "applicationDidBecomeActive" methods in my app. What else could be causing this?