# app crashes on cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview, crash-reports

I keep posting crash logs i receive from the client and It's good to know that I have been able to learn a lot and resolve these issues as well.

Here is another one down here:

```
Incident Identifier: 7971B91B-9462-4B2A-B8F1-A77EE1C4F75F
CrashReporter Key:   f3a4736dc8d450a3cb0ecb7367313dbbd816c484
Process:         MyApp [661]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/6DB30EF7-2B81-4631-9532-1785EAEA919B/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2009-10-08 00:33:08.830 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1 (7C144)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000022a
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3430deb8 0x3430a000 + 16056
1   UIKit                           0x33152a64 0x3314b000 + 31332
2   UIKit                           0x33152828 0x3314b000 + 30760
3   MyApp                           0x0000f26c -[DistanceViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (DistanceViewController.m:140)
4   UIKit                           0x331ee180 0x3314b000 + 668032
5   UIKit                           0x331eddd8 0x3314b000 + 667096
6   UIKit                           0x33199324 0x3314b000 + 320292
7   UIKit                           0x3319750c 0x3314b000 + 312588
8   UIKit                           0x331932d0 0x3314b000 + 295632
9   QuartzCore                      0x329161b8 0x3290a000 + 49592
10  QuartzCore                      0x32915ed4 0x3290a000 + 48852
11  QuartzCore                      0x3291583c 0x3290a000 + 47164
12  QuartzCore                      0x3291546c 0x3290a000 + 46188
13  QuartzCore                      0x3291d5d4 0x3290a000 + 79316
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3143282a 0x31423000 + 63530
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3147a340 0x31423000 + 357184
16  CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
17  GraphicsServices                0x325323a0 0x3252e000 + 17312
18  UIKit                           0x3314ec28 0x3314b000 + 15400
19  UIKit                           0x3314d228 0x3314b000 + 8744
20  MyApp                           0x00002090 main (main.m:13)
21  MyApp                           0x0000202c start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a002 0x31423000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
4   WebCore                         0x31e196f0 0x31d95000 + 542448
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080c4b8 0x3080b000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3080f094 0x3080b000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3147a002 0x31423000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31479c18 0x31423000 + 355352
4   Foundation                      0x31382998 0x31328000 + 371096
5   Foundation                      0x3137bac6 0x31328000 + 342726
6   Foundation                      0x31329d0e 0x31328000 + 7438
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308312f0 0x3080b000 + 156400
1   CoreFoundation                  0x314437e2 0x31423000 + 133090
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3089c720 0x3080b000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083e4d8 0x3080b000 + 210136
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3083dc9c 0x3080b000 + 208028
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x3122c1c4 0x31225000 + 29124
4   WebCore                         0x32355104 0x31d95000 + 6029572
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x308367b0 0x3080b000 + 178096

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0000022a    r1: 0x33ed0220      r2: 0x0011bdb0      r3: 0x0543b938
    r4: 0x06242a80    r5: 0x0011bdb0      r6: 0x3858e380      r7: 0x2fffe268
    r8: 0x33ec8e4c    r9: 0x329b2b4a     r10: 0x0011bdb0     r11: 0x001487d0
    ip: 0x3853f4b0    sp: 0x2fffe248      lr: 0x33152a6c      pc: 0x3430deb8
  cpsr: 0x200f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x3cfff +MyApp armv6  <4f870047a559c2e98c81aecafda6f73d> /var/mobile/Applications/6DB30EF7-2B81-4631-9532-1785EAEA919B/MyApp.app/MyApp
   0xeb000 -    0xecfff  dns.so armv6  <957f94410f77a351749ac39d2b4b4abe> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv6  <c9ed2fd4b6ad0b603479d414cb382dd5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30005000 - 0x30011fff  CoreVideo armv6  <c31d33c7629e4f7b14a659f06f17674e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30061000 - 0x30078fff  OpenGLES armv6  <c31f4982bc65e67356e9b692f9976b1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30079000 - 0x301cdfff  AudioToolbox armv6  <065ac06f6e9f6bc62555565581a50637> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x30218000 - 0x30223fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <28bbad866f148b0d0adda83a01cec8f8> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3035d000 - 0x3040afff  ImageIO armv6  <8d44717aa7e4314848108d49b42ce576> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3040d000 - 0x30441fff  Security armv6  <36f9d8ca8c4e037e14edd6ae95524b24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3045f000 - 0x30493fff  SystemConfiguration armv6  <818346d31133d475739fe3c3b35b5bd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30630000 - 0x30677fff  CoreMedia armv6  <07c13fb5ab31a52dfc3a50be02898f1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3067b000 - 0x30687fff  IAP armv6  <3752a21b994225b12069f929bf9b19d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x30725000 - 0x3072dfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6  <6673f222acee5f3a208169712387862a> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x307a9000 - 0x307b7fff  libz.1.dylib armv6  <c4d3d79ffaa7e13f556cd5f9c9fceff2> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x307b8000 - 0x30808fff  Celestial armv6  <6ccb9601cfba52fc5b7740e70fb565b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x30809000 - 0x3080afff  CoreSurface armv6  <12f13b59faf0107d8536963b1552c481> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3080b000 - 0x30931fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6  <7bcb29dde047a859e6f57f2e9e63d38f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30986000 - 0x30988fff  ArtworkCache armv6  <49b8fea9eb3f6e7d2241d94cc241bbd2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x309f6000 - 0x309fbfff  ITSync armv6  <cad602d917d800f848e522d835c3a031> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30b45000 - 0x30b4bfff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <74ead45f4f6840457b982e3a5cc30055> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30b4d000 - 0x30b79fff  CoreLocation armv6  <ac2b8ebbcb03f7a57c61c9a5eaa5b3d7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x30b7e000 - 0x30bbcfff  VideoToolbox armv6  <15ea0e25a764b445ce59401f09c2787d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30bbd000 - 0x30cd3fff  MediaToolbox armv6  <4930d982e746b906ca6fac74e30d361b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x30ef7000 - 0x30f16fff  Bom armv6  <fcd9e839c0d1a25cbf59a08cc60fea3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30f1a000 - 0x30f1cfff  CrashReporterSupport armv6  <db3c3a983db3d53f6199dafb8b472bfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31043000 - 0x3112afff  MusicLibrary armv6  <3deebbf46222551b71d0121b6360308b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x31196000 - 0x3119afff  libgermantok.dylib armv6  <de2afc812c51de295be8f32b73dcb77d> /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib
0x311ac000 - 0x31221fff  MediaPlayer armv6  <8e2efee9a7b8abcfddec740e95c87ed3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31225000 - 0x31322fff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <303af93622bcb0c4b68ed62b55d124fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31328000 - 0x31420fff  Foundation armv6  <8ddca22a76a5f2bc91f55c87eea8e9a5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x31423000 - 0x314cffff  CoreFoundation armv6  <a40c65b893c6ca5c0b632d2804ad59d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x314fc000 - 0x31556fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <e346522412f1e957d9cee6511c66bdc9> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x31557000 - 0x31557fff  vecLib armv6  <c8a08b45effd5eb35a476a969628e52d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31558000 - 0x3155bfff  MobileInstallation armv6  <e9617b1538fe22f2d6eb91156d130409> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3158f000 - 0x315fcfff  CFNetwork armv6  <19088cf3f0b4f667b52482ac6ab99690> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31603000 - 0x3160dfff  libkxld.dylib armv6  <8c6d9927c48ad08cfae540d60af17b6a> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x3160e000 - 0x31617fff  SpringBoardServices armv6  <a2849d569ba1e7a4083aec5be693f055> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31622000 - 0x3165ffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6  <640dc156b068d347f6c83a27adad6d06> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31660000 - 0x3169efff  CoreText armv6  <c21aa763bf62e82e8a1f062c3e201e84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x316ac000 - 0x316bcfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <f1b3998fcf7b60cee74b3e03fc94bf31> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x316f7000 - 0x31703fff  DataDetectorsCore armv6  <b9c577725d045e68e3b485a0513a95dc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x317c5000 - 0x31872fff  WebKit armv6  <b555f14fc6c288f8725843055d936507> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31933000 - 0x3193afff  WebUI armv6  <0426244613c88091f61c8a056285da5d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x31d2b000 - 0x31d2bfff  Accelerate armv6  <21e1dc9fad96f0d51afbeb7f7e006aaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31d95000 - 0x324e8fff  WebCore armv6  <28b391254b0edba93084f458e5805787> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x324f7000 - 0x3251efff  AppSupport armv6  <d8d247ecb9f5a3ff92583048a5da264c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3252e000 - 0x32539fff  GraphicsServices armv6  <8629b6affa7c7752ab3c702f1c694325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x325f8000 - 0x326eefff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <893355592f660060653383b29f42d102> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x326ef000 - 0x32729fff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <cf9cc6079374718dce29cba9de48b993> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32848000 - 0x32895fff  IOKit armv6  <035ec9372089422af1ccdb17d72ac091> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x328da000 - 0x328e9fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <6d87ea09ffe173f3d356514e7382bd95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3290a000 - 0x329b4fff  QuartzCore armv6  <cb65d19d96053b411b9a1c68f8f20a33> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x329d6000 - 0x329f4fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6  <e2f1ba98b2a7b91e91896cea1db932e4> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32a02000 - 0x32a2cfff  MobileQuickLook armv6  <98be398458dd7bc7faa3e9f21095b744> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileQuickLook.framework/MobileQuickLook
0x32a2d000 - 0x32be7fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <58e0bf5baaceb205917d03050a0ac954> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32cee000 - 0x32d58fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <1982380fa8b60e63fd29559efb58d1f0> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32d59000 - 0x32d5afff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <436a03767758117cc9ecec8417f2d185> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32eb0000 - 0x32eb7fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <faaee75832afeaf9d352318edd62970b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x32eb8000 - 0x32ef2fff  CoreTelephony armv6  <56a514c096120e8a1e1bb52b8645699b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x330ce000 - 0x330f1fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <5e02a84096d714b4f8a38aa8f4107b85> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33149000 - 0x3314afff  liblangid.dylib armv6  <232d2e6eb6afe91ca61aaac4d37009e5> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3314b000 - 0x33f3cfff  UIKit armv6  <dfcffbbb1e8813d91fe5fd5daf69ed11> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33f74000 - 0x33fd5fff  GMM armv6  <45ce64a42afbb59806bf588439b4bfc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x33fda000 - 0x33fe4fff  DataDetectorsUI armv6  <d730977336f18295ddd6167cbe157a9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x33fe5000 - 0x34040fff  CoreAudio armv6  <92290f4dba14837427eaa399a55929cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34150000 - 0x34156fff  MBX2D armv6  <0e5d686d0e641a8efc5dc2003c37e2f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x34170000 - 0x3418efff  AddressBook armv6  <d221b21a3d8594abc8ee717ae6f77076> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3419b000 - 0x341a5fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <48254d8d389dc9ecf90688e227ddba1a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x341f0000 - 0x341f4fff  IOSurface armv6  <1b951baaae45efbbae825b670612f478> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x341f5000 - 0x342f6fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <aceb70042ae76cfec9838f6771db48d8> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3430a000 - 0x343adfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <c3df9efc40404bc1865caacbf6209a1e> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

When I go to line no. 140 in DistanceViewController.m (crashing point, as suggested by log), i find:

```
cell.backgroundImage.image = barImage;
```

Where "barImage" is a UIImage defined in this class and initialized in initWithNibName method as:

```
barImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bar.png"];
```

I do not release barImage as I have not alloc/retain it anywhere. Also, distanceViewController's initWithNibName is only called once in the app.

Can anybody point me to where I should be focusing on to get rid of the crash here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+[UIImage imageNamed:] returns an autoreleased image; if you don't retain it, it will go away the next time the event loop returns. It sounds like you're calling imageNamed: in your init method, but trying to use the image in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. This would cause a crash.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [App crashes after launching on OS 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524529/app-crashes-after-launching-on-os-3-1) perhaps if you used the same OS in development as your client is running themn you would find the crashes before you released the code.

You at least would have the correct symbols to give some idea and be able to run in the debugger

Comment: I have built the app on OS 3.0 while my client has 3.1. I don't see any crashes on simulator and my device (both have 3.0)

Comment: By the way, i am the author of question you referred to.

Comment: Yes I know - and given your comment "I have built the app on OS 3.0 while my client has 3.1" - most responders think the problem is that and you need to run in dev under 3.1